# Как проверить тип переменной

Tags: node.js

Необходимо проверить является ли переменная x числом. Пробовал

```
if (typeof x != "number") { 
  console.log('Не число') 
} else { 
  console.log('Число')
}
```

Но оно не работает. Оно всегда пишет "Не число". Как можно проверить переменную?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var year = prompt('Write a number');
if (year.replace(/\s/g, '').length === 0 || isNaN(year)) {
 alert('Не число!');
} else {
alert('Число!');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Все работает.

```
var x=10;
if (typeof x != "number") { 
  console.log('Не число') 
} else { 
  console.log('Число')
}
```

пишет "число"

Чему у вас х равно?

Comment: let x = '20';
Вывод: Не число
let x = 'fafsawr';
Вывод: Не число

Comment: ну правильно если записать число в кавычках то это уже строка. Если вам надо понять является ли значение строки числом то это совсем другое.

Comment: этот пример кстати во втором ответе.